# Can't figure out the rebus

Tags: rebus

Here is the rebus. I'm not sure what the answer is, hopefully, someone has seen this before and could explain it to me? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Please refer to where you got the puzzle; plagiarism is not allowed ton PSE

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Probably

> Bigger and better

Because

> The arrow is pointing the the bottom phrase, which is a bigger "& better".

Comment: Oh, that makes sense now! Thank you very much!

Comment: Can I ask how you got it to show the text after I hover my mouse over it?

Comment: @iiRosie1 Sure, you type >!Text to be hidden here

Answer (score 1):

It might be

> "Bigger and Better"
>  because the second Better is Bigger than the first Better

Answer (score 0):

I think this means

> **Far better than this**

Because

> The small better is far away from the big better if you look this with a three dimensional view. And the arrow is pointing towards or referring to **this**(the big better)